# Java: access to website refused with htmlunit

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit

I am trying to access a webpage on a Virtual Machine with Htmlunit/webclient etc. My code is doing just this for the time being.

When I run the program, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://www.google.com refused
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
>       at autoPEC.main(autoPEC.java:7)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
>       ... 13 more

**Problem**: When I run the same piece of code on eclipse on my laptop(outside the Virtual Machine), the code runs fine without any error.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this on the Virtual Machine? Because the code seems to be good. Is there some security which is prevented my IDE on the VM from accessing the site or something else?my antivirus?

**How can I access a website on my Virtual Machine just the way I am accessing it outside the VM?**

Comment: You can't access **any** website from Java.  You may only access the web sites that allow access by code other than browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question. I wrongly explained my problem